# How to install PenPot on docker using Portainer and Traefik?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, portainer

I am trying to install PenPot using Portainer and Traefik. I have entered my docker-compose file into Portainer and created the stacks. In Traefik I have created a proxy network for the frontend of PenPot to connect to. On the back end I am using the default network for the backend of PenPot and the database to use. As far as I can tell (and I am just starting out with Docker, so I am trying to learn) everything looks to be set up correctly.

However when I look into the logs for backend PenPot, I see that it can't connect to the database. It fails with the following message:

```
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "penpot"
```

I have checked the password used and it is spelt correctly in both instances and the password doesn't use any special characters. I have gone over the settings multiple times and I can't for the life of me figure out why I am getting this error. Can I not have multiple networks? Am I missing something in my configuration?

This is my docker-compose file. Hopefully someone can point out the error that I am making.

```
version: "3.5"

networks:
  default:
    external: false
  proxy:
    external: true

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  assets_data:

services:
  frontend:
    image: "penpotapp/frontend:latest"
    hostname: frontend.penpot
    volumes:
      - assets_data:/opt/data
    depends_on:
      - penpot-backend
      - penpot-exporter
    networks:
      - default
      - proxy
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=proxy
      - traefik.constraint-label=proxy
      - traefik.http.routers.penpot-http.rule=Host(`penpot.mydomain.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.penpot-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.middlewares.penpot-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.routers.penpot-http.middlewares=penpot-https-redirect 
      - traefik.http.routers.penpot-https.rule=Host(`penpot.mydomain.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.penpot-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.penpot-https.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.penpot-https.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.services.penpot.loadbalancer.server.port=80

  penpot-backend:
    image: "penpotapp/backend:latest"
    hostname: backend.penpot
    volumes:
      - assets_data:/opt/data
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis

    environment:
      ## Standard database connection parameters (only postgresql is supported):
      - POSTGRES_DB=penpot
      - POSTGRES_USER=penpot
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=penpot
      ## Redis is used for the websockets notifications.
      - PENPOT_REDIS_URI=redis://penpot-redis/0
      ## Should be set to the public domain where penpot is going to be served.
      - PENPOT_PUBLIC_URI=https://penpot.mydomain.com
      ## Feature flags.
      - PENPOT_FLAGS=enable-registration enable-login disable-email-verification
      ## By default, files uploaded by users are stored in local
      ## filesystem. But it can be configured to store in AWS S3.
      - PENPOT_ASSETS_STORAGE_BACKEND=assets-fs
      - PENPOT_STORAGE_ASSETS_FS_DIRECTORY=/opt/data/assets
      ## Telemetry. When enabled, a periodical process will send anonymous
      ## data about this instance.
      - PENPOT_TELEMETRY_ENABLED=false
      ## Email sending configuration. By default, emails are printed in the
      ## console, but for production usage is recommended to setup a real
      ## SMTP provider. Emails are used to confirm user registrations.
      - PENPOT_SMTP_ENABLED=true
      - PENPOT_SMTP_DEFAULT_FROM=Penpot <no-reply@mydomain.com>
      - PENPOT_SMTP_DEFAULT_REPLY_TO=Penpot <no-reply@mydomain.com>
      - PENPOT_SMTP_HOST=mail.mydomain.com
      - PENPOT_SMTP_PORT=587
      - PENPOT_SMTP_USERNAME=XXXX
      - PENPOT_SMTP_PASSWORD=XXXX
      - PENPOT_SMTP_TLS=true
      - PENPOT_SMTP_SSL=false
    networks:
      - default

  penpot-exporter:
    image: "penpotapp/exporter:latest"
    environment:
      # Don't touch it; this uses internal docker network to
      # communicate with the frontend.
      - PENPOT_PUBLIC_URI=http://frontend.penpot
    networks:
      - default

  postgres:
    image: "postgres:14"
    restart: always
    stop_signal: SIGINT
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS=--data-checksums
      - POSTGRES_DB=penpot
      - POSTGRES_USER=penpot
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=penpot
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - default

  redis:
    image: redis:7
    restart: always
    networks:
      - default
```